# How to upgrade joomla's built-in bootstrap to latest version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I'm using joomla ver. 3.2.3 and it is using bootstrap 2.3.2. How can I update it so I will be able to use latest bootstrap version which is 3.2.0?

Comment: You wouldn't upgrade, you would use the new one. But you'll have to  rewrite all of the layouts as overrides in your template. Basically making a template where you do that and where you load that framework. There are some docs about doing things like this on docs.joomla.org.

Comment: And how can I use the new one? Does basically overwriting the core bootstrap files with the new ones make that happen?

Comment: No that will break your site. Do you want Bootstrap 3 for the front-end or the backend?

Comment: NO you need to put them in a separate location. You definitely should not overwrite you will regret it since the whole core is built around BS2.

Comment: @cppl For the front-end

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you sound like you're building a front-end template.

Most templates maintain all `assets` in inside the template's specific directory. e.g.

`/templates/mytemplate/css/`
`/templates/mytemplate/js/` and
`/templates/mytemplate/images/` would be suitable places for the Bootstrap files.

You can see this with the built-in `Protostar` template paths to CSS and JS files are:

`/templates/protostar/css/`
`/templates/protostar/js/`
`/templates/protostar/images/`